# "From around the world" vs "Around the world"

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between "from around" and just "around" in the following context or in general?

> I participated in an event where I met some people from around the world.
>
> I participated in an event where I met some people around the world.

Comment: I wouldnt consider it too localized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I participated in an event where I met some people from around the world.

This means that those people were from around the world; the event itself happened in 1 place (maybe in your home town), and all those people from all around the world came there and met you.

> I participated in an event where I met some people around the world.

This means that during the event you traveled around the world and met some people.